# show $x$ is not tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis

> Wrong statement: $x\notin\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$,i.e. $x$ is not a tempered distribution.

However, we know polynomials($P$) or even $Pf$ for $f\in L^p,1\leq p\leq \infty$ , are tempered distribution(am I right?).

But here's my proof for this wrong statement.

take any $\varphi_n\rightarrow0$ in $\mathcal{S}$,the Schwartz space,  then $(x,\varphi_n)\rightarrow 0$ if $x\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, now let's consider function 
$$
\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}},|x|<1\\
0,|x|\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$,
and consider $\varphi_n=\epsilon_n\varphi(\frac{2}{n}(x-n))$, then $supp \,\,\varphi_n=[\frac{n}{2},\frac{3n}{2}]$, and they are all in Schwartz space for sure. Now consider the following integral:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\varphi_ndx&=\epsilon_n\int_{\frac{n}{2}}^\frac{3n}{2}x\varphi(\frac{2}{n}(x-n))dx\\
&\geq\epsilon_n\frac{n}{2}\frac{n}{2}\int_{-1}^1\varphi(x)dx
\end{split}\tag{1}
$$

then if we take $\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$, equation (1) will go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity. which is a contradiction.

What's wrong with this proof? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown $\phi_n\to 0$ in $\mathcal S.$ What is the topology on $\mathcal S$?

Comment: @Dap since $\epsilon_n$ goes to 0 and bump function is bounded, so $\phi_n\rightarrow 0$

Comment: look up the topology on $\mathcal S$ - it isn't pointwise convergence. (The $\int\phi_n$ comment wasn't directly relevant so I deleted it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence $\phi_n\to 0$ in $\mathcal S$ is defined by all these norms tending to zero:

$$\|\phi_n\|_{{\alpha ,\beta }}=\sup _{{x\in {\mathbf  {R}}^{n}}}\left|x^{\alpha }D^{\beta }\phi_n(x)\right|.$$

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space))

You haven't shown that these norms tends to zero, so you haven't shown $\phi_n\to 0$ in $\mathcal S.$ In fact you have given a proof by contradiction that $\phi_n\not\to 0$ in $\mathcal S.$

Comment: my test function is compactly supported，so of courese in schwartz space

Comment: @DuFong: I never it wasn't in $\mathcal S.$ I said $\phi_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ to $\mathcal S.$

Comment: I see. You are right

Answer (score 0):

Actually, x is tempered distribution.

details: using (c), take p = 1 and take N=2

Source : Rudin Functional Analysis 7.12 example (c) and (d) (book p190 -191)
[image]